# psycopg2 execute('SELECT version()') failed

Tags: python, psycopg2

hi~ I want to access pgsql through psycopg2, but an error is reported.I use the same command and have no problem in the pgsql.

```
import psycopg2

connect = psycopg2.connect(database='xxx',
                           user='xxx',
                           password='xxx',
                           host='xxxx',
                           port=1521)

cursor=connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT version()')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/z30007746/PycharmProjects/untitled3/pt_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    cursor.execute('SELECT version()')
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at end of input
QUERY:  DECLARE 
BEGIN 
CONTEXT:  FUNCTION: plspl_anon_func
LINE 1 FROM "CREATE": BEGIN
```

Comment: You are able to connect , the query is failing becoz of syntax error , try removing `;`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I removed ```;``` But the same error is reported. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/z30007746/PycharmProjects/untitled3/pt_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    cursor.execute("select version()")
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at end of input
QUERY:  DECLARE 
BEGIN 
CONTEXT:  FUNCTION: plspl_anon_func
LINE 1 FROM "CREATE": BEGIN

Comment: @Vaebhav `pms.c_info_vendor` should there be a `.` in between?

Comment: I changed the sql to ```select version()```. It still looks like the same error